# Tomcat8 security

Tags: java, security, tomcat8

Hi I have issues with Tomcat8 Security, please help me.

I have my app with Apache Struts1 in Tomcat 6.
When I try login getting HTTP 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied, But my config security I think is correct, this is my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>EEEExample Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/gp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/hp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/sp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/gi</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>LOCK</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRADORES</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/gp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/hp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/sp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/gi</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Example FFFForm-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRADORES</role-name>      
</security-role>
```

My login.jsp form have next:

```
<form method="POST" action='j_security_check' >
  <table border="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
  <td align="right">Usuario:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">CContraseña:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Entrar"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

My Realm class, have authenticate method, and startInternal, stopInternal methods too.
The authenticate method return Principal class correctly then I don´t know why getting HTTP 403. I hope see index.jsp
Thank you for your help.